# Time to read data in Linux is different in formatted disk and Disk with deleted data

Tags: linux, performance, benchmarking, disk, ext4

Trying read calls on disks using read() command on 2 different kind of disks: 
 
`ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

1. Newly Formatted Disk
2. Disk where data was inserted and Deleted

Environment:

- Disk Size: 500 GB
- Disk Type: SSD
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3
- File System: ext4

Avg Read Time for Formatted Disk (in microseconds): 127.11 
Avg Read Time for Disk (Data was inserted and deleted) (in microseconds): 514.76

Script for above:

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 512
#define TIMEOUT 30

int count;
time_t start;
long total_seek_time = 0, total_read_time = 0;
int unread_complete_block_count = 0;

void done()
{
    time_t end;
    time(&end);
    if (end < start + TIMEOUT)
    {
        printf(".");
        alarm(1);
        return;
    }

    if (count)
    {
        printf(".\nResults: %d seeks/second, %.2f ms random access time\n",
               count / TIMEOUT, 1000.0 * TIMEOUT / count);
        printf("Total seek time: %ld, Avg seek time: %.2f\n", total_seek_time, 1.0 * total_seek_time / count);
        printf("Total read time: %ld, Avg read time: %.2f\n", total_read_time, 1.0 * total_read_time / count);
        printf("Unread Complete Block Count: %d\n", unread_complete_block_count);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void handle(const char *string, int error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        perror(string);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

long getMicrotime()
{
    struct timeval currentTime;
    gettimeofday(&currentTime, NULL);
    return currentTime.tv_sec * (int)1e6 + currentTime.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[BLOCKSIZE];
    int fd, retval;
    unsigned long numblocks;
    off64_t offset;
    long seek_start, seek_end, read_start, read_end;

    int buf_ret_val = setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    if (buf_ret_val == 0)
    {
        printf("Buffer successfully allocated\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate buffer. Error code, %d\n", buf_ret_val);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Seeker v2.0, 2007-01-15, "
           "http://www.linuxinsight.com/how_fast_is_your_disk.html\n");

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: seeker <raw disk device>\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    printf("File Descriptor: %d\n", fd);
    handle("open", fd < 0);

    printf("Device size in sectors: %u\n", BLKGETSIZE);
    printf("Device size in bytes: %lu\n", BLKGETSIZE64);

    retval = ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE, &numblocks);
    handle("ioctl", retval == -1);
    printf("Benchmarking %s [%luMB], wait %d seconds", argv[1], numblocks / 2048, TIMEOUT);
    time(&start);
    srand(start);
    signal(SIGALRM, &done);
    alarm(1);

    for (;;)
    {
        offset = (off64_t)numblocks * random() / RAND_MAX;

        seek_start = getMicrotime();
        retval = lseek64(fd, BLOCKSIZE * offset, SEEK_SET);
        seek_end = getMicrotime();
        handle("lseek64", retval == (off64_t)-1);

        read_start = getMicrotime();
        retval = read(fd, buffer, BLOCKSIZE);
        read_end = getMicrotime();

        handle("read", retval < 0);

        long current_seek_time = seek_end - seek_start;
        long current_read_time = read_end - read_start;

        // printf("Current seek time (us): %ld\n", current_seek_time);
        // printf("Current read time (us): %ld\n", current_read_time);
        if (retval != BLOCKSIZE)
        {
            printf("Didn't read complete block");
            unread_complete_block_count++;
        }

        total_seek_time += current_seek_time;
        total_read_time += current_read_time;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Compile: gcc {name}.c 
Run: ./a.out /dev/{sdx}

Need to understand why is it happening?

Comment: Little known secret: Linux disks can be defragged, and they boot and run faster. Don't believe the literature.

Answer (score 0):

An empty SSD can "know" it's empty, after TRIM, so it's like reading a sparse file.  Data has to go over the SATA bus, but (I think) not necessarily come from flash cells at all.

So yes it matters what you did to the block device.  The flash remapping layer inside the SSD is firmware running on a fairly powerful microcontroller with lots of RAM.